# spaCy custom parser for chat intent semantics

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Does the `spaCy`'s parser for custom semantics (`train_intent_parser.py`) example work for multiple `ATTRIBUTE`s?

```
TRAIN_DATA = [("find a cafe with great wifi", {
    'heads': [0, 2, 0, 5, 5, 2],  # index of token head
    'deps': ['ROOT', '-', 'PLACE', '-', 'QUALITY', 'ATTRIBUTE']
})
```

I modified above example to have two attributes, `wifi` and `pool`, and tried to train below two data sets, but the `QUALITY(great)` only works for one `ATTRIBUTE`, but not two `ATTRIBUTE`s.

```
("find a hotel with great wifi and pool", {
    'heads': [0, 2, 0, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2],  
    'deps': ['ROOT', '-', 'PLACE', '-', 'QUALITY', 'ATTRIBUTE', '-', 'ATTRIBUTE']
}),

("find a hotel with great wifi and pool", {
    'heads': [0, 2, 0, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2],  
    'deps': ['ROOT', '-', 'PLACE', '-', 'QUALITY', 'ATTRIBUTE', '-', 'ATTRIBUTE']
})
```

What's the right way to annotate for two or more `ATTRIBUTE`s?

Thanks,

```
Python version: 3.6.3
spaCy version: 2.0.5
Models: en, en_core_sm
Platform: Linux
```